# How to add 6 months to a series of datetime in Python?

Tags: python

If I have a series of date such as "2020-01-01,2020-01-02,...." Then how can I add 6 months to every date? The result should be "2020-07-01,2020-07-02,.....". In Excel I can use Edate function so is there any similar function that also works in python?

Comment: What if there are only start year and end year? For example, 2020-01-01 and 2022-12-31. Can I directly list all dates via timedelta?

Comment: You've just accepted an answer that is so out-of-whack with your question title, I don't know what you're expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
for i, date in enumerate(datelist):
    datelist[i] = date + relativedelta(months=+6)
```

datelist refers to your series with the dates

Comment: Once you have generated the list of dates, you can append it to your existing series with `original_list.append( datelist )` . 


reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html#pandas.Series.append

Comment: Yeah sorry, i fixed the answer

Comment: The question itself is ambiguous, but I saw generate dates and add to list so I answered accordingly

Comment: Fixed, didn't understand but now i get what OP wants, it works for me

Comment: It does now, added that, thanks for clarification in the question/answer haha